# dcos client installation failure - import concurrent.futures ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures

Tags: python, dcos

I just completed the installation of the dcos environment in the lab environment, and when I try to install the dcos client in on centos7 linux machine I got

```
**[root@rmavmdock5 dcos]# bash install.sh . http://10.120.1.187**
Installing DC/OS CLI from PyPI...

New python executable in /root/dcos/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/root/dcos/bin/dcos", line 7, in <module>
   from dcoscli.main import main
 File "/root/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcoscli/main.py", line 7, in <module>
   from dcos import config, constants, emitting, errors, http, subcommand, util
 File "/root/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcos/config.py", line 10, in <module>
   from dcos import constants, jsonitem, subcommand, util
 File "/root/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcos/jsonitem.py", line 5, in <module>
   from dcos import util
 File "/root/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcos/util.py", line 2, in <module>
   import concurrent.futures
ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures
```

I looked into google and find our similar case fixed running 'pip install futures' but even after install this the installation keeps failing

**[root@rmavmdock5 bin]# pip install features**

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): features in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): concepts<1.0,>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from features)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): graphviz<1.0,>=0.3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from features)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): fileconfig<1.0,>=0.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from features)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bitsets<1.0,>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from concepts<1.0,>=0.7->features)
```

**[root@rmavmdock5 bin]# pip install --upgrade features**

```
Requirement already up-to-date: features in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: concepts<1.0,>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from features)
Requirement already up-to-date: graphviz<1.0,>=0.3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from features)
Requirement already up-to-date: fileconfig<1.0,>=0.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from features)
Requirement already up-to-date: bitsets<1.0,>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from concepts<1.0,>=0.7->features)
```

**pip version**

```
[root@rmavmdock5 bin]# pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /root/dcos/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Checking the install script line by line i found that the dcos client installation process reported those errors when the install script tries to run

```
# storage dcos config set core.reporting true
```

but the whole process is working fine untill the dcos binary is configure with command

```
/root/dcos/bin/pip install --quiet dcoscli
```

, this command is the one that makes the dcos command available and seems that for any reason is not working properly

I've run the same command with the -v option (output is huge and don't know how to attach files), but the command ends

```
Successfully installed dcos-0.4.8 dcoscli-0.4.8 docopt-0.6.2 gitdb-0.6.4 gitpython-1.0.2 jsonschema-2.4.0 pager-3.3 pkginfo-1.2.1 portalocker-0.5.7 prettytable-0.7.2 pygments-2.1.3 pypng-0.0.18 pystache-0.5.4 requests-2.10.0 rollbar-0.13.2 six-1.10.0 smmap-0.9.0 toml-0.9.1 virtualenv-13.1.2
Cleaning up..
```

Comment: Watch your spelling: you want `pip install futures`, not `pip install features`. They're two different packages.

Comment: I am getting this error also (on OSX) and `pip install futures` isn't getting me anywhere `Requirement already up-to-date: futures in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 2):

the virtualenv env doesn't have futures.  install via the virtual env pip, not the system one.

from the dcos dir:

`bin/pip install futures`

then do your `bash install.sh . <url>` again